# how to interact with elements embedded in android.webkit.WebView using uiautomator

Tags: appium, appium-android

am working on android automation using appium & robot framework. for this am using robot's appiumlibrary. so i want to automate facebook login secenario in my application, but the problem is the fb login page on app is embedded to an webview. however in uiautomatorviewer able to focusand and find elements, but while running the scripts it throws an error element not found.

[image: screenshot]

what do i need to do in this scenario. i tried to fetch and then switch to context but there was no new or related context available. NATIVE_APP was the only one available.

Comment: You need to add some chrome options to your driver capabilities and change driver.context to interact with webview.  I don't remember the exact capabilities right now, but I will check it tomorrow at work and come back to you ;)

Comment: @Angusiasty - We have to enable setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled flag to see webview context, until that nothing will work. If I am wrong please correct me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To see the webview context using `driver.context()` method WebView debugging should be enabled; developer must enable ‘`setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled`’ flag in the `WebView` class. This flag enables debugging of web contents (HTML / CSS / JavaScript) loaded into any WebViews of app. Once this is done `driver.context()` method will return native and webview both contexts.

```
    Set<String> availableContexts = driver.getContextHandles();
    System.out.println("Total No of Context Found = "+ availableContexts.size());
    for(String context : availableContexts) {
        if(context.contains("WEBVIEW")){
            System.out.println("Context Name is " + context);
            driver.context(context);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Note - You cannot do this for third party app like facebook because you may not rebuild that app with webview debugger enabled.